# how can I find the error section in my Flutter app based on the exception log?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my exception log that I received it from Sentry (Sentry is an application monitoring platform):

```
_AssertionError: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize': RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#6c51b relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
  File "errors_patch.dart", line 46, col 39, in _AssertionError._doThrowNew
  File "errors_patch.dart", line 36, col 5, in _AssertionError._throwNew
  File "box.dart", line 1702, col 12, in RenderBox.size
  File "shifted_box.dart", line 213, col 37, in RenderPadding.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "flex.dart", line 765, col 15, in RenderFlex.performLayout
  File "button_bar.dart", line 349, col 11, in _RenderButtonBarRow.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "shifted_box.dart", line 209, col 11, in RenderPadding.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "shifted_box.dart", line 209, col 11, in RenderPadding.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "shifted_box.dart", line 209, col 11, in RenderPadding.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "custom_layout.dart", line 173, col 11, in MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild
  File "scaffold.dart", line 470, col 45, in _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout
  File "custom_layout.dart", line 242, col 7, in MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout
  File "custom_layout.dart", line 401, col 14, in RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 1269, col 11, in _RenderCustomClip.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 3226, col 14, in RenderOffstage.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "proxy_box.dart", line 115, col 13, in RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1769, col 7, in RenderObject.layout
  File "overlay.dart", line 702, col 15, in _RenderTheatre.performLayout
  File "object.dart", line 1632, col 7, in RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize
  File "object.dart", line 889, col 18, in PipelineOwner.flushLayout
  File "binding.dart", line 404, col 19, in RendererBinding.drawFrame
  File "binding.dart", line 867, col 13, in WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
  File "binding.dart", line 286, col 5, in RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
  File "binding.dart", line 1117, col 15, in SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
  File "binding.dart", line 1056, col 9, in SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
  File "binding.dart", line 972, col 5, in SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
  File "zone.dart", line 1190, col 13, in _rootRun
  File "zone.dart", line 1093, col 19, in _CustomZone.run
  File "zone.dart", line 997, col 7, in _CustomZone.runGuarded
  File "hooks.dart", line 253, col 10, in _invoke
  File "hooks.dart", line 211, col 3, in _drawFrame
```

full exception log : [link](https://sentry.io/share/issue/9f039ff809104fbb96fa487afabf0883/)

how can I find the error section in my Flutter app based on the exception log?
I meant is I finding an error widget that throws this exception

Answer (score 0):

```
_AssertionError
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1702 pos 12: 'hasSize': RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#6c51b relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
```

this is your error

Generally, all the errors are before the stack trace like before #0

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(24143): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/RepoOperation(24143): setValue at /Users/4f6X7j8Lq5UvFp8X5KTG1foxNCr2 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
E/flutter (24143): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(-3, Permission denied, ) // this is actual error
E/flutter (24143): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope 
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:571
E/flutter (24143): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:160
E/flutter (24143): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24143): #2      MethodChannel.invokeMethod 
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:333
E/flutter (24143): #3      DatabaseReference.set 
package:firebase_database/src/database_reference.dart:73
E/flutter (24143): #4      _EmailSignUpState.registerToFb.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutterexpensescanner/email_signup.dart:143
E/flutter (24143): #5      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47))
```

Like this

Comment: thanks, your mean is I can't find the error widget from this log?

Comment: run you  app with `flutter run -v` to see the complete logs.